# What happend to SQL Stored-Procedure in using of JPA?

Tags: database, nhibernate, stored-procedures, jpa, toplink

What happened to SP when we use of JPA?  Does JPA kill stored-procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA did not/will not kill stored procedures. You can use them both in your application. Saying that JPA killed stored procedures is almost like saying that JPA killed SQL. Plain-old-straight native SQL is still the best choice for some portions of your applications. Even if that application is mostly using JPA.

Comment: when do we have to use native-queries usually?

Comment: Lots of them. To name a few from the top of my head: queries using Window Functions, or Recursive Queries...